# aws s3 cli sync with watching folder live

Tags: bash, unix, amazon-s3, aws-cli

What would be the bash command that will continuously watch `jsondata` folder and sync that folder with s3 when changes happen to local folder.

Now I am running this command but it does not have a -watch flag.

```
aws s3 sync jsondata s3://mybucket/jsondata/
```

Comment: How fast do you need it to react? Does it need to be instant, or is it sufficient to sync at regular intervals (eg every 1 minute or 5 minutes)?

Comment: I can accept several seconds delay as changes happen.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, you can use **[incrontab](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-use-incron-monitor-important-files-and-folders/)** utility to watch over files and folders. Trigger the script whenever you receive a new file in folder. The script will contain aws sync command.

Comment: I finally chose this solution that works well and easy to setup.

Answer (score 2):

S3 Sync is a bash script that will setup automatic syncing between your local directory and Amazon S3, utilizing the inotify linux kernel utility and s3cmd. It can also sync from your S3 bucket to a local directory via cron.

https://github.com/jasonrichardsmith/s3_sync

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem and came across this stackoverflow question and figured there has to be a more convenient way to do this.

So I wrote a little npm module exactly for this purpose. it watches a folder and uploads file changes to an s3 bucket automatically. It's called [`s3-auto-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-auto-sync)

Once installed you can just run `s3-auto-sync -r us-east-1 -b my-bucket -d ./my-folder`. That's it.

PS: Use a bucket in the same region as you are located, this will significantly improve upload speed.

Comment: I´m wondering about the my-bucket section, do you use the s3://path because I´m constantly getting: **must be a valid bucket name -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html**

Comment: Also there is an issue when using an existing bucket. The region option is omitted, generating an issue that the bucket already exists (in another region). I made a PR to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are many options but here is one from a quick google search:

https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

Python script that can register for filesystem notifications and take an action as a response.  The examples shown at the link above can take a shell command (s3 sync, for example) that can be executed when a change in the directory is detected.

The [inotify_simple project](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/inotify_simple) is another alternative.  There are many options.